# Samsung Galaxy Tab can't detect intent filter browsable

Tags: android, url, url-scheme, galaxy-tab

I have created intent filter browsable and [scheme attribute](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) for my application, and it can run perfectly in HTC Desire S. But my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 just can't detect the filter whenever I click the link on browser. Here is my manifest :

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 

                <data
                    android:host="xxx.xxx.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/xxx/xxx"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Is there someone who used Samsung Galaxy Tab that have the same experiences? Thank you.

Comment: Why is it tagged with *Scheme*?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad, here's I have edited my question. Thank you. Do you have same experiences?

Comment: No, sorry. Good luck!